# How to make a single table appear on multiple sheet tabs and replicate edits across all the tabs google sheets apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to make a single table appear on multiple different google sheet tabs, while also syncing changes across all of them.

I have a task table and I'm wondering if it's possible to have a different sheet for each Timeline view (Today, Tomorrow, Next, etc) while also replicating edits simultaneously. I know I can use a filter function, however that just displays the data.

For example I have my Task Manager tab that has all tasks listed. In addition, I want a Today sheet that shows only the tasks with the Timeline of today. However, I would also like the ability to edit anything on a task row, like change the Timeline to Tomorrow, and this change would reflect back on the main task table.

[image]

I could add this function but it just pulls the data.  I also was thinking I could use apps script for this - but I don't know if even with using apps script I could achieve the desired results.

```html
=FILTER('TASK MANAGER'!A25:K41,'TASK MANAGER'!F25:F41="Today")
```

Does anyone have any thoughts if this would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with Filter Views. You can apply them to filter according to each day, even have one view for today, one for yesterday and so on

I suggest you consider this possibility. Other ways are via scripts, which could be a headache by implementing it, always syncing and checking every kind of modification, sorting issue and more. Hope it's useful! There are many tutorials and documentation online; here you have just one as [example](https://blog.golayer.io/google-sheets/google-sheets-filter-view#:%7E:text=Hide%20Columns&text=Simply%20select%20the%20column%20you,Choose%20%E2%80%9CHide%20column%E2%80%9D.)

I mean You use it everything in one tab with many filter views. Let me know how you find it